# How to retain unique ID in QGIS while running Least Cost Distance?

Tags: qgis, least-cost

I have to find the least cost distance from Junnar (19.209280, 73.872589) to a list of 207 points using the Least Cost plugin on QGIS (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/leastcostpath/).

My raster is HMI.tif (https://human-mobility-index.github.io/) which is on ESRI:54034 so I have reprojected my points to the relevant longitudes and latitudes (X and Y in the picture.)

However, when I run the least-cost plugin it drops the unique id (idnum) that exists in the original CSV file but generates random start and end point IDs for each of these points. It also drops the coordinates which leaves me unable to map the least cost distances back to the original dataset. How do I rectify this?

[image: The input attribute table]

[image: Output CSV]

Comment: Convert your csvs to geopackage datasets. The ID the plugin uses is the `fid`. You can join the least cost distances back to the target dataset using end point id -> fid.

Comment: @user2856 I did that but the plugin seems to be reassigning the fid since the final file arranges every point in ascending order of least cost distance.